# Using the value of a variable to select columns

Tags: r

I have some code that calculates quantiles and saves it under a new variable. Now I am trying to modify the code so I can use it in a loop. Here is a sample dataset, the original code, and the output.

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("Algeria", "Egypt", "Ethiopia"), 
                 ward_1 = c(25, 75, 35),
                 ward_2 = c(30, 185, 60))

df %>%
  mutate(
    ward_1_quant = case_when(
      ward_1 >= quantile(df$ward_1, 2/3) ~"High",
      ward_1 >= quantile(df$ward_1, 1/3) ~"Med",
      TRUE~"Low"
    )
  )

df <- data.frame(country = c("Algeria", "Egypt", "Ethiopia"), 
                 ward_1 = c(25, 75, 35),
                 ward_2 = c(30, 185, 60),
                 ward_1_quant = c(Low, Med, High))
```

Now I want to use the value of a variable "ward_num" to specify the column. I turn that into a string called "ward_name" and try to use it in the mutate(). Here is where I got stuck:

```
ward_num <- 2
ward_name <- paste0("ward_",ward_num)
df %>%
  mutate(
    paste0(ward_name,"_quant") = case_when(
      ward_name >= quantile(df[ward_name], 2/3) ~"High",
      ward_name >= quantile(df[ward_name], 1/3) ~"Med",
      TRUE~"Low"
    )
  )
```

r returns the error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in: "  mutate(
> paste0(ward_name,"_quant") ="

I think the issue is that I want to use the string in ward_name but the code is using ward_name literally. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

We may use `.data` with `[[`.  Also, the expression on the lhs of `=` is not permitted. Instead use `:=` and evaluate (`!!`) the `paste` expression

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    !! paste0(ward_name,"_quant") := case_when(
      .data[[ward_name]] >= quantile(.data[[ward_name]], 2/3) ~"High",
      .data[[ward_name]] >= quantile(.data[[ward_name]], 1/3) ~"Med",
      TRUE~"Low"
    )
  )
```

-output

```
   country ward_1 ward_2 ward_2_quant
1  Algeria     25     30          Low
2    Egypt     75    185         High
3 Ethiopia     35     60          Med
```

---

Or another option is to pass this in `across`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(ward_name),
   ~ case_when(.x >= quantile(.x, 2/3) ~ "High", 
    .x >= quantile(.x, 1/3)~ "Med", TRUE ~ "Low"), 
      .names = "{.col}_quant"))
   country ward_1 ward_2 ward_2_quant
1  Algeria     25     30          Low
2    Egypt     75    185         High
3 Ethiopia     35     60          Med
```

---

Or another option is to use `quantile` with `cut`

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(ward_name),
   ~ cut(.x, breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(.x, probs = c(1/3, 2/3)), 
      Inf), labels = c("Low", "Med", "High")), .names = "{.col}_quant"))
     country ward_1 ward_2 ward_2_quant
1  Algeria     25     30          Low
2    Egypt     75    185         High
3 Ethiopia     35     60          Med
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing around with `across()`, `!!` and its friends, I think it's better to use base R here.

```r
ward_num <- 2
ward_name <- paste0("ward_",ward_num)
ward_name_quant <- paste0(ward_name,"_quant")
df[[ward_name_quant]] <- case_when(
                         df[[ward_name]] >= quantile(df[[ward_name]], 2/3) ~ "High",
                         df[[ward_name]] >= quantile(df[[ward_name]], 1/3) ~ "Med",
                         TRUE ~ "Low"
                       )
```

Also, you can use `cut`, or `santoku::chop_quantiles()` instead of the `case_when` call. (Side note: `case_when` is often a code smell.)

```r
df[[ward_name_quant]] <- cut(df[[ward_name]], 
                             quantile(df[[ward_name]], c(0, 1/3, 2/3, 1)), 
                             c("Low", "Med", "High"), 
                             include.lowest = TRUE
                           )

# or

library(santoku)
df[[ward_name_quant]] <- chop_quantiles(df[[ward_name]], 
                                        c(1/3, 2/3), 
                                        c("Low", "Med", "High")
                                      )
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `[[` instead of `[` as this may lead to some buggy situations